# Python - Get the min coordinate element of a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have this 2d numpy array: `[[0,2],[0,3],[0,1],[1,0]]`. These elements represent points in `x` and `y` axes. So, for example, in `[0,2]` 0 is the `x` and 2 is the `y`.

I would like to get the point with the min `x` and min `y`. In this case, it would be `[0,1]`. I know I can easily do this with a for loop, but it takes too many resources. Is there a numpy function or something to calculate this?

Comment: numpy is also available on c++ and what I'm looking for is a numpy function so an answer written on c++ would be ok too. About your second question, yeah, that's why I have this this problem. [0,2], [0,3] and [0,1] has the min x but [0,1] is the only one with the min y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first find the min of `x`, then find the min of `y` for pair where `x` equals the min of `x`:

```
np.min(xy[xy[:, 0] == np.min(xy[:, 0])], 0)
```

```
In [1]: xy
Out[1]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]])

In [2]: np.min(xy[xy[:, 0] == np.min(xy[:, 0])], 0)
Out[2]: array([0, 1])
```

It is relatively fast, even for large array:

```
In [4]: timeit.timeit('np.min(xy[xy[:, 0] == np.min(xy[:, 0])], 0)',
                      'import numpy as np; xy = np.random.rand(100000, 2)', 
                      number = 100)
Out[4]: 0.06858562525758316
```

---

Old version which was a bit slower (before @OliverW. comment):

```
In [3]: timeit.timeit('np.min(xy[xy[:, 0] == np.min(xy, 0)[0]], 0)', 
                      'import numpy as np; xy = np.random.rand(100000, 2)', 
                      number = 100)
Out[3]: 0.20433111706540785
```

Comment: Note that if efficiency is what you're going for (judging from your timing results, you are), you might just want to change `np.min(xy, 0)[0]` into `np.min(xy[:,0])`. That way you won't have to find the minimum of the "x-column" too, which is wasteful.

Comment: @OliverW. Thanks! I was more interested in the complexity which is linear in both case but your version divide the computation time by a factor of 3 which is great (I have updated the answer)!

Comment: Yeah, I was looking to get a better optimization instead of just using a for lop. The timing you get is more than enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the NumPy built-in [`np.lexsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) to do such a sorting, like so -

```
xy[np.lexsort(xy.T[::-1])[0]]
```

`lexsort` gets the sorted indices that respects such a precedence, but does so in the opposite sense, i.e. the last element, then the second last element and so on until the first element. So, we need to reverse the order of elements, that's why the appended `[::-1]`. Also, `lexsort` works along each column instead of each row as needed to solve our case, so we needed that `transpose` before reversing.

Sample run -

```
In [235]: xy
Out[235]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]])

In [236]: xy[np.lexsort(xy.T[::-1])[0]]
Out[236]: array([0, 1])
```

Comment: Good edit, but I think there is a simple version of @Holt's answer, for this problem.